# GPX to shapefile tool error message

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, error, gpx

I downloaded the GPX to shapefile tool and when I use it I get the following error message: 1 No module named re Failed to execute (gpx2shp).

[image: Error Message]

Comment: This is the full error message: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named re
Failed to execute (gpx2shp).

Comment: Do you have this python file C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\re.py on your computer?

Comment: I don't have experience/knowledge of python but it appears i do have that re - python file.  It looks like i actually have 3 different re files.  I am assuming the py stands for the type of file??

Comment: Also says i have Python26.  Anyway thanks for your original post.

Comment: In either ArcCatalog or ArcMap, open the Python window and try typing in    import re    then press enter.  Any errors?

Comment: Yes i get similar error message - ">>> import re 
Runtime error <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named re"

Answer (score 1):

The script is failing to find the Python regular expression library, which is strange because re is part of core python.

You could open the Python console in ArcMap, and `import re` to see if the same error occurs.

As @artwork21 suggests, you could browse to your python installation and see if re.py exists.

You could start python from the command line and see what version is reported being installed (though re has been part of python since 1.6 or so). I'm not familiar with the tool you're using, but maybe you'll discover that python isn't in your path and this tool requires it?

**Adding python to path**

Follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318188/3479672). On step 4, enter `;C:\python26\ArcGIS10.0` (be sure to verify this. Will be the same path you followed to run python in one of your comments)

If, after logging out and back in, you can type python at a command prompt and it works, I'll bet this tool will run as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  However i think this is above my knowledge.  I have never worked with python before.  I was hoping there would be a easy fix that i could do.  Someone else i am working here at my office had no problems and we have downloaded the same tool and have the same group Arcview license.  If you have any other suggestions or guidance on how to do what you have stated above let me know.

Comment: Try this: Open a command prompt and just type 'python'. If you drop to a python shell, type 'import re'. If it complains about not knowing what python is, I'd be willing to bet the issue is not having python in your PATH environment variable

Comment: Okay, i tried that and it says that "python is not recoginized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".  Would I be able to add python to my PATH environment variable?

Comment: In Windows Explorer (or command prompt, but I'm guessing explorer may be easier), browse to C:\Python26\ArcGIS10 and run python.exe. You should see a prompt with >>>. Try 'import re' there.

Comment: Thanks again for your the suggestions.  From that location when i enter 'import re' and press enter i get a new prompt with no error message.  So i am guessing this means 're' is already here or the command has worked.  However i still get the same error message when i try to run this tool.

Comment: Cool. My money's on python not being included in your path environment variable. Editing my original answer with a link on how to add it

Comment: I ended up upgrading to arcgis 10.2 and now i have no problems.  Maybe there was something broken with my old 10.0 but it could be that i changed my environment settings for a class i took.  If you have instructions on how to add python to my path environment I would still like to know how to do this.  Thanks